# Mac Finder - Custom Grid Spacing

Tags: finder

Question:

Is there any way to increase the grid spacing in Finder for Icon View (or all the views) beyond the provided limit?

Reason:

I would like to get the list view similar to Windows Explorer with "columns" that auto extend to fit the full file names.

[image: My issue with the Mac Finder]]

[image: Desired view, shown in Windows Explorer]

(Same folder opened in both)

So far:

I have found XtraFinder to provide a solution but only for Column View.

Answer (score 0):

I was actually looking for the same adjustment, except to make the spacing smaller than the minimum, to minimize white space while looking through a folder of photos in icon / grid view. I was hoping there was a terminal command to access this setting.

For the issue you describe, I'm not sure why the ordinary list view is not sufficient — can't you make the name column arbitrarily wide to see full file names?